# How to implement Stack Iteration using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, stack, java-stream, java-9

I have a `Stack<Object>` and following piece of code:

```
while(!stack.isEmpty()){
    Object object = stack.pop();
    // do some operation on object
}
```

How this iteration can be implemented using Java 8 Stream so that it loops until the stack is empty and in every iteration the stack should be reduce by popping one element from top?

Comment: Streams should be used to derive new data from given data set. But you are also trying to change the stack. Using streams is not a good idea here. Unless you are fine with calling ```clear``` at the end.

Comment: `stack.stream().map(...) ...`
`stack.clear()`
I would avoid manipulating the data structure while using a stream on top of it. Most programmers would be surprised by this side effect when they read such code.
I case you are looking for a more 'elegant' syntax, consider wrapping the operation in an iterator.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that ```Deque``` is preferred over ```Stack```

Comment: In Java 9, there will be a 3-arg version of `Stream.iterate` (like a for loop -- initial value, lambda for determining end-of-input, lambda for determining next input) that could do this.

Comment: @BrianGoetz, thank you for the response. Could you please put your comment in the answer section so that I can accept it and it might come handy for other people. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java 9, there will be a 3-arg version of Stream.iterate (like a `for` loop -- initial value, lambda for determining end-of-input, lambda for determining next input) that could do this, though it would be a little strained:

```
if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    Stream.iterate(stack.pop(), 
                   e -> !stack.isEmpty(), 
                   e -> stack.pop())
          ...
}
```

Comment: This does not work because `isEmpty` is checked after `pop`, which means the last element is always missing from the stream. The same is true if `iterate` is used for iterators or enumerations (which admittedly makes no sense). I know it is consistent with both `for` (if `pop` is put into the _increment_ part) and `takeWhile` but still confusing. Enough so to even trip up the experts creating it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In case you don’t want to wait for [the Java 9 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38170812/2711488), here’s a stream factory which works under Java 8.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> pop(Stack<T> stack) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(
        stack.size(), Spliterator.ORDERED|Spliterator.SIZED) {
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                if(stack.isEmpty()) return false;
                action.accept(stack.pop());
                return true;
            }
    }, false);
}
```

Note that this reports the initial size of the stack, taking it for granted, which implies that you must not change the stack in-between (modifying a stream source in-between is a bad idea anyway). On the other hand, this will make certain Stream operations more efficient than the iterate variant.

Now, a general warning that applies to both variants. Stream sources that are modified due to an ongoing Stream operation, like popping the elements which the Stream consumes, can leave the source in an unpredictable state. Short circuiting operations may not consume all elements and in combination with parallel Streams, they still may consume more elements than needed for the terminal operation.

So analogous to [`BufferedReader.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--)

> After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line.

you should not make any assumptions about the `Stack` contents after consuming elements this way.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible using the stream of the stack since first it would be in first-in-first-out order and second since it is based on an iterator would throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Still possible but of course not recommended when compared to the simple for loop:

```
IntStream.range(0, s.size()).forEach(i -> stack.pop());
```

Comment: This codes does not account for stack change inside the consumer.